# How to insert a space after each comma in string if there is not one already?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to standardize an address.

Ex: 1234, some street, quebec (qc), g1g 1g1

I tried with Instr(MyStr, ",") combined with the Replace function.

It does work when there is no space, but puts a double space when there is one already. I want also to be sure that it does this to all commas in my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be 4 fields in a table. Concatenate them in query

```sql
Select Trim(zipcode) & ", " & Trim(street) & ", " & Trim(city) & ", " & Trim(whateverTheFourthValueRepresents) As StandardAdress From Table
```

For only one field in Table first replace all correct comma/blanks with only comma, then replace comma with comma/blank. Maybe you need to replace double blanks with a single one too.

```vb
Replace(Replace(MyStr, ", ", ","), ",", ", ")
```